# SublimeText: transpile ES6 to ES5 on save

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, ecmascript-6, babeljs

With the Less plugin I got a nice Less -> Css compilation whenever I save the file. How to get the same behavior with Babel to have ES6 code transpiled to ES5? Thanks

Comment: Are you explicitly looking for a sublime plugin, or just looking for any way to recompile on change? Babel's CLI tool can be passed `-w` to watch files for changes. How are you compiling now without sublime?

Comment: Transpiling jobs (or any build steps you can imagine) can also be done via [grunt.js/gulp.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/). Once setup you can run a watch task doing the routine jobs for you or you can manually trigger the build steps via CLI.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited** after @lukas-kabrt suggestion:

The `less2css` Sublime plugin, utilizes the [on_post_save()](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) event of the Sublime API, to listen for a file Save and then trigger the code that will compile the .less file automatically. Something similar can be accomplished for Babel ES6-to-ES5 compilation, by using this event in a plugin, and linking it to an external command that will auto compile the current file using Babel. This is a simple plugin for ST2, written in Python, that accomplishes this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin,os
from os.path import dirname, realpath

class BuildonSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

  def on_post_save(self, view):
    es6File = view.file_name()
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(es6File)
    if file_extension == ".es6":
      view.window().run_command('exec',{'cmd': ["/usr/local/bin/babel", es6File, "-o", filename+".js", "--source-maps", "inline"] })
```

Note: This plugin looks for .es6 suffixed files and compiles them to the appropriate .js file, e.g. myfile.es6, will be transpiled into an ES5 myfile.js file.

The `cmd` location `/usr/local/bin/babel` can be obtained on your system by running the `which babel` command on the terminal, if you're on Mac OS X.

Source code can also be found here: https://gist.github.com/kostasx/1d55c62edcee88375fc8

You can checkout the Sublime Plugin API documentation, if you want to mingle with the code above a little more.

Comment: Any idea what the last line turns into on Windows?

Comment: @StevenScaffidi You can try the following steps:

First, install babel CLI: `C:/> npm install -g babel-cli`

Then locate the executable path: `C:/>where babel`

Replace the cmd with the path you'll get, e.g on my installation:
`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\babel.cmd`

And don't forget to escape the slashes!

`view.window().run_command('exec',{'cmd': ['C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\babel.cmd', es6File, "-o", filename+".js", "--source-maps", "inline"] })`

Comment: I was trying \\babel and it wasn't working. Changed it to \\babel.cmd and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.